# How to show foreign letters like ø æ å for Android

Tags: android

How to show the letters like ø æ å in android Application, I want to show these characters in Full Project, Please Help How i Do it ?

Comment: these Characters are Coming in JSON and I am Displaying it into TextView but these special Characters not SHowing as the need to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the strings are read from a JSON document make sure to decode the JSON file correctly. That is, know the character encoding that was used for creating the JSON files and use that same encoding when decoding the files.

Assuming you already have an InputStream for reading your JSON document you can use something like this:

```
private static final Charset JSON_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

private JSONObject loadJsonObject(InputStream in) throws JSONException, IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, JSON_CHARSET);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    copy(reader, writer);
    return new JSONObject(writer.toString());
}

private static void copy(Reader reader, Writer writer) throws IOException {
    try {
        char[] buffer = new char[512];

        while (true) {
            int nChars = reader.read(buffer);
            if (nChars < 0) {
                break;
            }

            writer.write(buffer, 0, nChars);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Use a charset other than UTF-8 if necessary.

Comment: i am using iso-8859-1 in Input Stream , i need to change it UTF-8 ?

Comment: Use the character encoding the files were encoded with. If you know it's iso-8859-1 then use that!

Comment: hey can you tell how to show these symbols in typing, i want to implement, these symbols when related keyword is clicked, help please

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)` ? Naturally, strings should be stored in external resources string.xml, so `mystring` should be eg.

```
String mystring = getString(R.string.myStringResource);
```

Comment: i don't understand , How i can apply this?

Comment: I can see it's solved now, as you can see people were very helpul here, but it helps to spiecify your problem a bit more (e.g. I didn't know that it's about parsing JSON - I could provide more appropriate code snippet.). I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

put the special `strings.xml` under the `res/value-xxx/`

Comment: Will u elaborate your answer please

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to change the XML attribute of my layout file to UTF16 to get certain extended characters to display correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Comment: i am trying "iso-8859-1" in Input Stream